# R plot kernel densities for subsets of a dataset (conditional on char variable)

Tags: r, if-statement, plot, kernel-density

I want to plot kernel densities for specific subsets of my dataset. The subsets are to be identified by a char variable.
My dataset has the following structure (not my actual dataset but the general structure):

```
Char_var    var1   var2  var3  k_var
Material A                      2
Material B                      5
Material C                      7
Material A                      8
Material C                      4
.                               .
.                               .
.                               .
```

var1, var2,  var3 are other doubles but not necessary for this plot.

Generally, I coded it so far like this

```
dens1 <-  density(k_var) # How do I add an if statement for the Char_var here?
plot(dens1)
```

If I do it this way, I would need to write the code above for every material in my dataset. Is there a more elegant way to code that such that I get the density plots for every material or do I need to split it up for every material as I intended to do? ...as I have acutally more than three materials in my dataset.
Thanks!

Comment: You can get all densities with `dens <- tapply(dat$k_var, dat$Char_var, density)`. But if you have many different values in `Char_var` your plot of all of them may become a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the densities a simple way is to use a `tapply` loop.

```
dens <- tapply(dat$k_var, dat$char_var, density)
```

Now the plots. These densities are all plotted in the same graph and should be seen as just an example.

```
dx <- sapply(dens, function(d) range(d$x))
dy <- sapply(dens, function(d) range(d$y))

xlim <- c(min(dx[1, ]), max(dx[2, ]))
ylim <- c(min(dy[1, ]), max(dy[2, ]))

plot(0, type = "n", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, xlab = "", ylab = "")
for(i in seq_along(dens)){
  par(new = TRUE)
  plot(dens[[i]], main = "", col = i, xlab = "", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
}
```

[image]

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(char_var = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 10),
                  k_var = rnorm(40))
```

Comment: Thanks that helped! What would I need to change in the `dens -> ...` line to get the density for one specific value of `Char_var`?

Comment: @sh_student You must subset the data before, then `density(subdf)`. You can subset by any usual method, `subset(dat, Char_var = <value>)$k_var` or `dat[Char_var == <value>, 'k_var']`.